# Properties of the norm in a Euclidean Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I am aware of the fact that the Euclidean Norm does not need to be unique in a given domain, however my question is essentially: can we ensure that the properties of the norm remain the same? More specifically:

1. If we let the Norm function be $N$, is it always true that $N(a) = 0$ iff $a = 0$? Why?
2. When do we allow the Norm function to have the property of multiplicity? For example, from Ireland and Rosen comes the problem: From the properties of $N$ deduce the identity $$(a^2 + b^2)(c^2 + d^2) = (ac - bd)^2 + (ad + bc)^2$$ I let $\alpha = a + bi$ and $\beta = c + di$ and use the fact that $N(\alpha)N(\beta) = N(\alpha\beta)$.  However, is this assumption justified? I have seen some sources assume multiplicity of the norm, while others do not state it in the definition.

Thanks.

Comment: 1.) is a deceptively simple question.

Answer (score 2):

1. The condition N(a-bq) < N(b) is invariant under replacing N(x) by N(x)+1.
2. It is not known whether any Euclidean ring is Euclidean with respect to a
   multiplicative function. Multiplicativity of the Euclidean function is used
   in general for simplifying the proof that Euclidean rings are factorial (UFD),
   but I do not know whether e.g. the ring ${\mathbb Z}[\sqrt{14}]$, which was 
   shown to be Euclidean with respect to the minimal Euclidean function by Harper,
   is Euclidean with respect to a multiplicative function.

Comment: what does mean your 2. concretely ?

Comment: Thank you.  Can you explain how 1.) shows that N(a) = 0 iff a = 0? Also, how would you go about doing the problem in 2.) without the assumption of multiplicity?

Comment: It does not prove it, it shows that if N is a Euclidean function with N(0) = 0 then the function M(x) = N(x)+1 is also Euclidean.